# Would a vantablack coating on the starlink satellites cause overheating problems?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, starlink, insulation

I'm an amateur astronomer and have recently being hearing space x catching alot of flack for the amount of reflection the satellites would cause. While I believe that program is more important than my hobby, I wonder if coating the satellites in vantablack would help eliminate that issue. I'm aware that material absorbs almost all light, so I could see the internal components overheating. Is it possible to dissipate or harness that extra heat?

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer which is more or less the same:
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39165/is-it-feasible-to-paint-spacex-starlink-satellites-black-so-as-not-to-frequently